# n error occurred. java.io.FileNotFoundException: test_scores.txt n error occurred. s.txt (annot find the file specified) .io.FileInputStreanputStr

Tags: java

My code is not working and I was wondering what I need to to do to fix it

This is the question and expected output:
Write a program that reads a text file named test_scores.txt to read five
test scores. The program should display a each test score, letter grade for each
test score, average of five test scores and finally the letter grade for the average
test score.

Write the following methods in the program:

- `averageCalculation` – this method should accept the total of all test
  scores as argument and return the average of the scores.
- `gradeDetermination` - this method should accept a test score as an
  argument and return a letter grade for the score, based on the following
  grading scale:

```
Score Letter Grade
90-100 A
80-89 B
70-79 C
60-69 D
Below 60 F
```

Please write the Javadoc comment before each method which explains the
working of method, parameters it receives and return value.

Expected Output:

```
Score for test1 is: 83.0
Grade for test1 is: B
Score for test2 is: 75.0
Grade for test2 is: C
Score for test3 is: 66.0
Grade for test3 is: D
Score for test4 is: 51.5
Grade for test4 is: F
Score for test5 is: 96.5
Grade for test5 is: A
Average of test scores is:74.4
The final Grade is: C
```

This is my code:

```
package HW5;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

 public class TestScores {


 public static double calAverage(double score1,double score2,double score3,double score4,double 
 score5) {  
 double average;
 average = (score1 + score2 + score3 + score4 + score5) / 5;
 return average;
 }

 public static String determineGrade( double testScore ) {
    String letterGrade = "";
    if(testScore < 60 ) {
        letterGrade = "F";
    } else if(testScore < 70) {
        letterGrade = "D";
    } else if(testScore < 80) {
        letterGrade = "C";
    } else if(testScore < 90) {
        letterGrade = "B";
    } else if(testScore < 100) {
        letterGrade = "A";
    }
    return letterGrade;


 }

  @SuppressWarnings("resource")
  public static void main(String[] args)  {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    Scanner sca70nner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numberOfScores = 5;
    
    for(int currentScore = 1; currentScore <= numberOfScores; currentScore++ ) {
        System.out.println("Please enter score");
    
        try {
            File myObj = new File("test_scores.txt");
            Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myObj);  
            while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
              String data = myReader.nextLine();
              System.out.println(data);
            }
            myReader.close();
          } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred.");
            e.printStackTrace();
          } 
        }  
      } 
}
```

Comment: It seems you just didn't pass the good path, the txt file may not be at the same place. Also why executing your code mulitples times in a for-loop ?

Comment: Can you please give your topic a meaningful title and append the real error message?